# AWS Gzip compression not working in java for isBase64Encoded

Tags: node.js, base64, aws-lambda, gzip, aws-java-sdk

> I have been working on Gzipping the response, but its work's fine in nodejs, but the same code is not working in java platform. After digging further i found that the key isBase64Encoded : true is not correctly been identified in the client( Chrome browser specifically)

```
public class ExampleHandler1 implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest,AwsProxyResponse> {

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
        AwsProxyResponse response = new AwsProxyResponse(200, Collections.singletonMap("X-Powered-By", "AWS Lambda & serverless"), "Aaytu");
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> headermap = new HashMap<>();
            headermap.put("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            headermap.put("Content-Type", "text/html");
            String responseString = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(GzipCompressor.compress("Hello there..!!!").getBytes());
            AwsProxyResponse retVal = new AwsProxyResponse(200, headermap, responseString);
            retVal.setBase64Encoded(true);
            return retVal;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `retVal.setBase64Encoded(true)` doesn't try to "help" you by automatically base64-encoding the response?  This would mean the response is double-encoded.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Tried removing the base64Encoded flag but still the issue is same.